# How to use mysql LIKE with wpdb?

Tags: php, posts, functions, mysql, wpdb

as per title I need to use LIKE operator to delete a row on db programmatically with $wpdb.

I wanna use `$wpdb->delete` to remove an occurrency but I don't know how to set the `LIKE` operator because in `WHERE` it requires an array that assign a single value or another array.

I ask you if this syntax is correct.

`$wpdb->delete('wp_posts', array('post_type' => 'flamingo_inbound', 'post_content' => '%'.$mail.'%'));`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the Codex, the delete method will not accept the `LIKE` operator. You'll be better off just using the query method.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'flamingo_inbound' AND post_content LIKE %s", '%'.$mail.'%');

$wpdb->query($query);
```

Hopefully `$mail` doesn't have a % or _ character otherwise you need to escape it before you build `$query`like so:

```
$mail = $wpdb->esc_like($mail);
```

Comment: And yet, of course you should always do proper escaping - hoping that user input is nice is rather risky ;)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż before fire that kind of query I do all the controls for sure

Comment: @jdp tomorrow I will try! Thanks a lot! I will tell u here.

Comment: @jdp seems to not work your solution

Comment: @Jacob Peattie ..thanks for the edits. @Pierpaolo Ercoli ...check the edited query string. Do a var_dump on `$query` and see what the query looks like.